# Background image - rescaling height and width independently

Tags: html, css, webkit

I want to have a div with a background image specified in CSS, and I want the background image to appear at a certain offset. I already know how to do that part. I also want to be able to set an arbitrary size for the div, and for the image to be rescaled accordingly. That's the part I'm having trouble with. I know about the [background-size](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-background-20020802/#background-size0) CSS attribute, but that doesn't give me any way to have independent control over the X and Y axes.

Is this even possible? I only need to support recent versions of WebKit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake - the document that I linked to seems to be outdated. `background-size` does, in fact, allow for specifying the height and width independently, like this:

```
background-size: 400px 200px;
```

Comment: Compatibility for this is limited.

Comment: @Dustin: yeah, I know. Fortunately, my compatibility needs are limited too. I wouldn't use this for general-purpose web design.